# manipulate return result for webservice using soapui

Tags: web-services, soapui

my GUI app communicate with taht webservice. for example
at GUI,
 **enter number : '1'**
then the webservice send back

```
price : $10
quantity : 30
```

currently, the vendor webservice is not yet finished. but i need to test my GUI wheter the design looks good for the 'price' and 'quantity' column.

sorry that i am newbie in soapui and have no idea how to start, although i finished reading the tutorial.

Do I need to create a mockup webservice to start?
i got a webservice link from vendor `(.asmx)`
i open the .asmx link at IE and got the send and request xml format.

Can i make use of that xml in soapui? and how?

Answer (score 1):

check out http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/mock-services.html to learn how to create a mock service from a wsdl.

If you do not have access to the vendor wsdl then you can use any other wsdl and create a mock service using that wsdl and just replace the xml with something your GUI expects.

Also, as your gui makes a call to the webservice, you would need to update the web service endpoint in your Application to point to the mock service.

Now just start up your mock service and away you go..